# PHP require does not work in root folder

Tags: php, require

I am using this to require a file when the user clicks the submit button on the form. This code is locaded in blog.php. When I have this file in the folder /includes/, the code works perfectly, but I want this file to be in the root folder. When I add it in the root folder, I get this error:

> Warning: require(../includes/addbloguser.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pentaslash\blog.php on
>   line 27
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '../includes/addbloguser.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\blog.php on line 27

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

      require '../includes/addbloguser.php';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should probably remove `..` from the filepath. Remember: Always use absolute filepaths.

Comment: even if i do remove it , it does not change the error message. I dont get it why this is happening , does it matter that I use PDO ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PDO. It's all about the filesystem. Just use absolute paths and you won't have that problem. Define in a global php file a constant which includes the absolute path to the root directory of your project and then you can just use that constant.

Comment: Absolute path seem to did the trick thanks very match =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem induced by using relative filepaths. Your relative filepath worked while the file `blog.php` was in the folder `includes` because with `../` you were going one directory up (to your root directory) and then back inside `includes`. But since you moved the file one directory up (to your root directory)  you are going with `../` one directory up, outside of your root directory and then try to go into the folder `includes`, but the folder doesn't exist in the directory above of your root directory (well, if you have luck it does, but the file doesn't exist or it does but the wrong one).

To prevent this you should always use absolute filepaths, that way you can move `blog.php` everywhere as long as your file `addbloguser.php` stays in the same location.

A easy way to get the absolute filepath to your project is to define a constant which evaluates to `dirname(__FILE__))` in a global file in your project's root directory. That way you can always use the constant to do things with files and prevent to modify files to correct relative filepaths if you change something.

E.g. `global.php` is inside your root directory, then you will just write this

```
define('IN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__)); //__FILE__ is a magic constant and includes the absolute filepath to the current file -> global.php
```

And if you now include in `blog.php` said file `global.php` (or the other way around) you can use for your filepaths the defined constant and it will look like this

```
require IN_DIR.'/path/to/file.php'
```

In this case that would be

```
require IN_DIR.'/includes/addbloguser.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, shouldn't it be:

```
require './addbloguser.php';
```

Try using

```
require __DIR__ . '/addbloguser.php';
```

or

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/addbloguser.php';
```

so you can get better error messages and see what's missing.